# Online page is losing styling and edits compared to offline page

Tags: html, css, web-hosting

I ran into a problem this evening that I don't really understand. I just uploaded some edits to a page on my site along with the updated CSS stylesheet and a new .js file, but a lot of the style is missing or not functioning properly.

Has anyone experienced this? And how do you suggest I debug this? I've tried to upload the pages again, but the same thing happens.

Also, just to clarify. The content is there but it is not displaying how it should, given the js and css commands.

Comment: Check the console in your browser's developer tools to see if any of the files that are being loaded have failed. The css and js files may not be linked properly in your HTML head.

Comment: Could be a caching issue; try turning on the "Disable cache while devtools is open" option in devtools, or run your code in an anonymous browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- hard refresh the page using Ctrl+F5 to void the web cache. The browser is probably reading the content from the cache. You can temporary rename the css file to force the browser loading new files.

2- Set expires for content (So visitors wont need to use hard refresh).
([How to set content expire](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661(v=ws.10).aspx))

3- Check The console to find if there is error about file addresses or other possible fails.

Comment: Thanks! #1 fixed the problem.